Why are the column dividers in the first line disappearing, and is there a way to refer to count the number of lines in a table before it's completed?
I'm trying to define a new environment that wraps tabularx to set up some rowcolors and automatically numbers rows in the table. However  I can't figure out why the first two dividing lines are disappearing in the tabularnx table here.
I would love to be able to replace Count? in the tabularnx table with the value of rowno at the end of the table, but I'm not sure if that would be possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcounter{rowno}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{tabularnx}{mmmm}
        {
            \setcounter{rowno}{0}
            \tabularx{#1}{|>{\stepcounter{rowno}\therowno}#2}
            \rowcolor{gray!50}
            \multicolumn{1}{r}{#3} & #4 \\
            \hline
        }
        {
            \endtabularx
        }

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularnx}{\columnwidth}{c|c|}{dCount?}{tabularnx}
 & a \\
 & b \\
 & c \\
\end{tabularnx}

\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|c|c|}
    \rowcolor{gray!50}
    d3 & tabularx \\
    \hline
    1 & a \\
    2 & b \\
    3 & c \\

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}

Outputs:


use \refstepcounter not \stepcounter then you can put \label{abc} in the last row and \ref{abc} is your dcount value

\multicolumn eats the line.  Try {r|}.

a tabularx environment must have at least one X-type column. if you want two cs or an r and a c or whatever, use tabular instead. if you need dcount to be a number even on the first run, you can record the value as a property and specify a default, then reference that property rather than using \ref{abc} directly. that doesn't seem required from your example, though.

@DavidCarlisle - updating to refstepcounter and a label just seems to result in question marks in the dx field:
\tabularx{#1}{|>{\refstepcounter{rowno}\therowno}#2}
with: \label{abc} in the closing braces of \NewDocumentEnvironment
...
\begin{tabularnx}{\columnwidth}{c|c|}{\ref{abc}}{tabularnx}
https://i.imgur.com/BDDDCRq.png
Is this the correct usage?

@JohnKormylo - {r|} keeps the divider ,but it seems to begin the count at the first line of the table, which isn't what I'm looking for, and it  includes a literal r— after the value.

@cfr - thanks for catching that. I was using an override of an X-type column in the full document, but I'd missed that in the example. Could you clarify what you mean when you say 'even on the first run'? I'm not too familiar with properties - cheers

@Epithet as you noticed, \ref{} will produce question marks the first time you compile and only resolve to the number after you compile again.

@cfr if I recompile it only resolves to an empty value, not the count that I was expecting - full example here https://pastebin.com/hyca2fJ0 as comments don't seem to be the right place for multi-line snippets
